# What is the best way to deal with server side data saved as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to handle global variables when they are necessary.  For example JSON that is inserted server side with PHP into the web page. `var data = <?php getData() ?>`

There seems to be 3 options.
1 leave it for garbage collection
2 leave off the var initialization of the variable and delete the variable
3 just set the variable to null and again leave it to GC.

Or there may be some other way that I haven't thought of I am open to suggestions.  Though I would prefer not to use ajax in this situation.  Also, it is not feasible to insert the variable data inside of the actual javascript code because I minify it.

EDIT:
The reason I am asking is the data could be potentially large and I was wondering what is the best way to deal with it.  Also, I am not sure how long garbage collection takes; so maybe it is really a non-issue. I don't know?

Comment: Are you worried about this because you've actually got performance problems?

Comment: Please rewrite the question in clearer form. Not clear what is the problem.

Comment: you don't mention why GC is important here. Is it a large amoutn of info?

Comment: @Pointy @awongh no I am planning out a program and it has the potential to have a lot of data placed in the variable.  So I was wondering what the best way deal with it once I have accessed it.

Comment: If you set the variable to null, then all you have to worry about is what happened to all the data that was copied here and there when you "accessed it" :-)

Comment: @Pointy not if I use `JSON.parse();`

Comment: uhh ... what?  How would that make any difference at all?  If the information is sent to the browser in any form, then it's there until it's garbage collected.

Comment: @Pointy I meant that I were to set the variable to null I would save it to another variable using JSON.parse

Comment: Well OK, I guess; if you save it to another variable, won't that also be using up memory?

Comment: @Pointy true but if I use  JSON.parse and save it to a variable within the scope then I have two instances of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that `var data = {...}` was embedded in the JavaScript and did not come from PHP -- where would be an appropriate place to put that?

This doesn't change and generally should be "smallest applicable scope" which may very well be a global window property -- although I would generally argue against this as I favor "modules" or other designs.

There are some potential issues to watch out for wrt. closures, unintentional bindings and very (100MB+) large structures. If the data is loaded-once then not needed anymore then, by all means, *let the object become unreachable* (through scope termination -- my preferred approach -- or assigning null to the variable referencing it, etc) but for the most part:

> > We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time -- Knuth

Happy coding.

Remember: `delete` does not destroy an object and variables are not GC'ed (they can, however, keep an object reachable). Objects are only GC'ed when:

1. The object is no longer reachable and;
2. the GC feels like it.

Comment: thankyou for the detailed response.  Probably this instance would fall into the 97% of time, but I like trying to figure out the if this were to become a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since no global variables get recycled by the GC, even if not being used by any function, you will have to `delete data;` or `delete window.data;` if out of scope

Comment: `window.data = null` or similar will suffice -- *variables* are not GC'ed, *objects* are.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is that you have to ask the server for the whole chunk of information then you have three options.

1: You can use `delete`

2: you can write this info into a structured DOM element and have the JS get it within a particular scope (which would then be GC'ed later), i.e., `div id="somefoo" class="invisible-div"><?php getData('somefoo'); ?></div>, then: var somefoo = $('#somefoo').text();`

this solution requires you to parse this info and structure it before it gets to the JS though. Depending on your needs this may or may not be a good thing.

3: ajax call.

The meta concern is that you don't want this data floating around after you've done what you wanted with it, and that there's no memory leak.

**Or** perhaps this isn't even much of a concern? I would think that you would only run into GC concerns if getData() returns a huge amount of data. Usually js GC collection concerns have to do with the memory allocated in the course of running your script, not in the input data. You may want to use, for example, the code profiling tool in google chrome, which will tell you your js memory usage. -For example, just testing it out, it tells me that gmail's memory usage was 36MB. You should evaluate what the acceptable bounds of memeory usage is, how much getData() takes up and go from there. Who knows, you may not even have to GC it.